# images are not displaying after publish

Tags: asp.net-mvc, image

I have a webpage in asp.net mvc. And, it simply displays a picture from the images folder. When I'm working on the local machine, it works fine but after I publish it to the website, image is shown as broken.

I checked the server and it seems like the picture uploaded to `wwwroot/myapplication/images`

My code for showing the image is:

```
<img src='@Url.Content("~/images/super.png")' />
```

Comment: you know what is the problem. Fix it then

Comment: but i dont know the solution, thats why i asked

Comment: I assume that's a typo, but the path on your sever is referencing the wrong folder (`image` instead of `images`).

Comment: first i wrote it wrong, then i corrected it. Both folders are /images

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless you have a typo in the question, the images were uploaded to `/image`, but the `<img src` is pointing to `/images`

Comment: What do you get when you try to access the image directly? `mydomain.com/images/super.png`?

Comment: i dont have any other page that has image in it or any css file.

Comment: You might not have IIS set up to serve static files. Try this: http://gurustop.net/blog/2009/10/12/funny-problem-windows-7-iis-7-5-images-css-not-showing/